# How to use useState (in React) to prevent from clicking a div more than once?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to fix my current bug where I have 6 clickable divs with `onClick()` events. Upon clicking `div` 'a','b' or 'c' for example, the count will increment by 1. After that, those divs cannot be clicked again. So far, I'm using `useRef()` and set attribute to 'disabled' but that is not working.

Another question is if it's possible to extract this to make a reusable component for other games that has the same `div` properties but different correct answers.

My code for `updateScore` and `onClick` as below:

```
  import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
    const ClickScore = ({ taskNumber, numberOfAnswers }) => {
  const [grid11, setGrid11] = useState("");
  const [grid12, setGrid12] = useState("");
  const [grid13, setGrid13] = useState("");
  const [grid21, setGrid21] = useState("");
  const [grid22, setGrid22] = useState("");
  const [grid23, setGrid23] = useState("");
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  const grid11Clicked = () => {
    setGrid11("clicked");
  };
  const grid12Clicked = () => {
    setGrid12("clicked");
  };
  const grid13Clicked = () => {
    setGrid13("clicked");
  };
  const grid21Clicked = () => {
    setGrid21("clicked");
  };
  const grid22Clicked = () => {
    setGrid22("clicked");
  };
  const grid23Clicked = () => {
    setGrid23("clicked");
  };
  let gridRef = useRef();

  const onGridClick = (e) => {
    if (gridRef.current) {
      gridRef.current.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  };

  const updateScore = () => {
    if (taskNumber === 1) {
      if (grid12 || grid21 || grid23 === "clicked") {
        setScore((prevScore) => prevScore + 1);
      }
      return `${score}/${numberOfAnswers}`;
    }
  };

  const clickHandler12 = () => {
    setGrid11("clicked");
    updateScore();
    onGridClick();
    console.log("disabled");
  };
  const clickHandler21 = () => {
    setGrid21("clicked");
    updateScore();
    onGridClick();
    console.log("disabled");
  };
  const clickHandler23 = () => {
    setGrid23("clicked");
    updateScore();
    onGridClick();
    console.log("disabled");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p id="score">{score}</p>
      </div>
      <div
        onClick={grid11Clicked}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          border: 1,
          borderColor: "blue",
          left: 23,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 37.91,
          zIndex: 10,
          borderStyle: "solid",
        }}></div>
      <div
        onClick={grid12Clicked}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          border: 1,
          borderColor: "red",
          left: 298.86,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 37.91,
          zIndex: 10,
          borderStyle: "solid",
        }}></div>
      <div
        onClick={grid13Clicked}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          border: 1,
          borderColor: "red",
          left: 600,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 37.91,
          zIndex: 10,
          borderStyle: "solid",
        }}></div>
      <div
        onClick={clickHandler21}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          border: 1,
          borderColor: "red",
          left: 3,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 212.91,
          zIndex: 10,
          borderStyle: "solid",
        }}></div>
      <div
        onClick={grid22Clicked}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          border: 1,
          borderColor: "red",
          left: 298.86,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 212.91,
          zIndex: 10,
          borderStyle: "solid",
        }}></div>
      <div
        onClick={clickHandler23}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          border: 1,
          borderColor: "red",
          left: 600,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 212.91,
          zIndex: 10,
          borderStyle: "solid",
        }}></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ClickScore;
```

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work out.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const GridCell = ({ style, onGridClick }) => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (!clicked) {
      setClicked(true)
      onGridClick()
    }
  }
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        border: 1,
        zIndex: 10,
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        ...style,
      }}
      onClick={handleClick}
      diabled={clicked}
    ></div>
  )
}

const ClickScore = ({ taskNumber, numberOfAnswers }) => {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0)

  const onGridClick = (row, col) => {
    if (taskNumber === 1) {
      if (
        (row === 1 && col === 2) ||
        (row === 2 && col === 1) ||
        (row === 2 && col === 3)
      ) {
        setScore((prevScore) => prevScore + 1)
      }
      return `${score}/${numberOfAnswers}`
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p id='score'>{score}</p>
      </div>

      <GridCell
        onGridClick={() => onGridClick(1, 1)}
        style={{
          borderColor: 'blue',
          left: 23,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 37.91,
        }}
      />
      <GridCell
        onGridClick={() => onGridClick(1, 2)}
        style={{
          borderColor: 'red',
          left: 298.86,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 37.91,
        }}
      />
      <GridCell
        onGridClick={() => onGridClick(1, 3)}
        style={{
          borderColor: 'red',
          left: 600,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 37.91,
        }}
      />
      <GridCell
        onGridClick={() => onGridClick(2, 1)}
        style={{
          borderColor: 'red',
          left: 3,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 212.91,
        }}
      />
      <GridCell
        onGridClick={() => onGridClick(2, 2)}
        style={{
          borderColor: 'red',
          left: 298.86,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 212.91,
        }}
      />
      <GridCell
        onGridClick={() => onGridClick(2, 3)}
        style={{
          borderColor: 'red',
          left: 600,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 212.91,
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Good answer!  Breaking it up into separate components for the Grid and the GridCell is definitely the right approach towards making it reusable.  A next step would be to pass the correct positions as a prop, or to pass an `isCorrect` callback function.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion. The code worked except when I clicked the correct grids, the score kept incrementing. I wonder why the disable attribute is not working. Does it only apply to button tag?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ref's, you can set flag array of booleans, to know if that particular button is clicked, if not let the handler function run, otherwise just pass null as handler function to onClick.

```
    Const Comp = () => {
      const [clickedArr, setClickedArr] = useState(new Array(6).fill(false));


      const handleClick = (index) => {
        // if not this button clicked before, than only do work
        if (!flagArr[index]) {
           setClickedArr(prev => {
             const newArr = [...prev];
             newArr[index] = true;
             return newArr;
           });

           // do other things
         }
       };

       return (
         <>
           {/* just provide indexes to handle click function, either by yourself
             or by mapping over your data */}
           <div onClick={clickedArr[0] ? null : e => handleClick(0)}>content</div>
           <div onClick={clickedArr[1] ? null : e => handleClick(1)}>content</div>
         </>
       )
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I never used flag variable before. Where did you set flagArr?

Comment: by flag array I did not mean, literally flagArr. I meant just an array in state, which could keep reference for particular button, if it has clicked before. In this case clickedArr is that "flagArr". so here I created array of 6 elements corresponding to each button, and initially stored false, and when each button get clicked, just updating element in array at that index to true. and than checking in return statement, if it has been clicked before just provide null as click handler

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

```
const Comp = () => {
  const [avoidExtra, setAvoidExtra] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if(!avoidExtra){
      setAvoidExtra(true);
      // do other things
    }
  }

  return <div onClick={handleClick}>Hi, I'm here to be clicked</div>
}
```